# Unity slider interaction with controller

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider, uislider, virtual-reality

So I have a laser pointer attached to my controller, shooting rays and triggering events whenever I press the tigger.
Tho it still has one or two buggs ([Unity VR Controller UI Interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900322/unity-vr-controller-ui-interaction)), I have a more general question.

The UI needs some kind of slider. And I can't figure out how to make my pointer collide with the slider and behave in a slider-ish way. When I press my button, it currently ends up setting the slider to zero and not letting me drag it. 
Thankful for any tipps on how to make them actually slide, since my ridgidbody-cube doesnt move and doesn't allow movement! Unitys documentation on e.g. the beginDragHandler isn't really helpful...

Cheers, Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your enter/exit events already works, juste check the x (or the axis corresponding on your slider) of your "laser" every frame or so, and increase/decrease the value of the slider based on the delta between two check.

Hope it is clear, it should not be hard if you already have your events sets up !

Comment: Good idea! Hoped to get Unitys UI System to understand it, but your definitly right. Thanks!! :) 
Any idea for the other thread on why my pointerClick event won't work?

Comment: What I use for my VR project is when user "click" (be it click, keypress or w/e), I raycast in the same direction of the laser and depending on the tag/name of the hit object I do what I want to

Comment: I don't quite remember but I don't think so. I've a trigger collider on my objects, and they're all on a layer for objects I can interact with. Then I just raycast to that layer and do what I want with the collisions